# "Internal server error" returning SelectList through ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying to retrieve data from database in .NET MVC, and populate a dropdown list with it.
The controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetCity(string name)
    {
        var cities = from c in context.Cities
                        orderby c.Name
                        select c;
        var chosenCities = cities.Where(c=>c.Name== name);
        return Json(new SelectList(chosenCities, "CityID", "Name"));
    }
```

The jquery ajax script:

```
$(function () {
    var countrySelect = $("#country-dropdown");
    var citySelect = $("#city-dropdown");
    countrySelect.change(function () {
        citySelect.prop("disabled", false);
        citySelect.empty();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetCity")",
            data: { name: countrySelect.val() },
            dataType: ("json"),
            success: function(cities){
                $.each(cities, function(i, val){
                    citySelect.append("<option value=\"" + val.CityID +
                        "\">" + val.Name + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function(ex, status, err){
                alert("Couldn't retrieve data: " + ex + " "
                    + status + " " + err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Results in "Internal server error.".

Comment: The issue is with your C# code. What is being returned from your LINQ query? Are you sure you can serialise a `SelectList` to JSON? It would be better to serialise a class and then update your UI based on that.

Comment: You should be able to get more details of the error than just "Internal server error". An internal server error just means that your server code threw some kind of unhandled exception. You should have some way of logging and retrieving information on this error or alternatively you can attach a debugger to the server and see the exception. This exception will tell you more precisely what has gone wrong and where.

Comment: @Chris As I can tell there are no unhandled exceptions on the server side.

Comment: Use you browser tool to inspect the response (Network tab) to determine what the error is. And you returning a `SelectList` (you should be returning just an anonymous object containing the 2 properties you need) which does not contain a properties `CityID` and `Name` - its `Value` and `Text`)

Comment: And you making a GET call, so you need to specify `return Json(..., JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Apparently, the query does not return any data from the database. When I convert the chosenCities IQueryable object to a List object, the Count property is 0. I guess something's wrong with the query.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, this solved the internal server error. I'm still not getting any data from the query, but I think I know where I made the mistake in that regard... A question, if I may: is it preferable to use 'POST' for this since no data is being posted on the server?

Comment: Your not changing any data (modifying your database) so it can be a GET, but it can also be a POST (that's really up to you). As far as not returning any data, you need to debug your code. But I suggest that you return `cities.Where(c => c.Name== name).Select(c => new { CityID = c.CityID, Name = c.Name });` (there is no point returning a `SelectList`, but if you do, then you need to change your javascript to `"<option value=\"" + val.Value + "\">" + val.Text + "</option>"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke, I've solved the problem. There was also a mistake in the query.

What I was trying to do is a cascading select list, using two lists; the second list would get populated based on the value from the first list.
So the EF query should have been `cities.Where(c=>c.Country.Name==name)` as shown below. But more importantly, **the reason I was getting the Internal server error is because I was using 'GET' instead of 'POST'** to fetch my data. This requires adding `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet` in the `Json(...)` arguments list:

```
public JsonResult GetCity(string name)
    {
        var cities = from c in context.Cities
                        orderby c.Name
                        select c;
        var chosenCities = cities.Where(c => c.Country.Name == name).Select(c => new{ Value = c.CityID, Text = c.Name });
        return Json(chosenCities, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
    }
```

Also there were some modifications in the JS code. When iterating over the returned data, the `CityID` and `Name` properties of the `City` class are bound to the `Value` and `Text` property of the object provided as the argument in the `success` function respectively.
This is the modified code:

```
  $(function () {
        var countrySelect = $("#country-dropdown");
        var citySelect = $("#city-dropdown");
        countrySelect.change(function () {
                citySelect.prop("disabled", false);
                citySelect.empty();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetCity")",
                    data: { name: countrySelect.val() },
                dataType: ("json"),
                success: function(cities){
                    $.each(cities, function(i, val){
                        citySelect.append("<option value=\"" + val.Value +
                            "\">" + val.Text + "</option>");
                    });
                },
                error: function(ex){
                    alert("Couldn't retrieve data: " + ex);
                }
                });                
        });
    });
```

Thank you to all who helped with this issue.

Comment: Please read my comments to your question. You should not be creating a `SelectList` - its just pointless extra overhead and means your sending extra data (e.g. the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`) to the view which you never even use. Just create a collection of anonymous objects

Comment: What do you mean by "the reason I was getting the Internal server error is because I was using 'GET' instead of 'POST"? You're fetching a city by its name, sounds like a typical GET request to me.

Comment: Read the following sentence, after the bold part. If the second argument is removed in the return statement, the error is thrown.